# Use resources to set foreground colour of a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a resource file that contains the colours that I want to use in my project. I've successfully used these resources to set the style of my WPF windows and controls. What I;m struggling to achieve is to use these same resources to programatically change the foreground colour of a textbox. I'm using C# and WPF.

This is my resource file and it's stored in a /Resources/Colours.xaml file.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<!--Application Colour pallette-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultColour" Color="#FF193B60"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BaseColour" Color="#FF2E5076"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightColour" Color="#FF506F93"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundColour" Color="#FFB7D7F9 "></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AlternateColour" Color="#FFB7D7F9"></SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HeaderColour" Color="#FF02162B"></SolidColorBrush>
<Color x:Key="Media.DefaultColour">#FF193B60</Color>
<Color x:Key="Media.BaseColour">#FF2E5076</Color>
<Color x:Key="Media.HighlightColour">#FF506F93</Color>
<Color x:Key="Media.ForegroundColour">#FFB7D7F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="Media.AlternateColour">#FFB7D7F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="Media.HeaderColour">#FF02162B</Color>
```

I've merged the resourcedictionary in the App.xaml file

```
   <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://Application:,,,/Resources/Colours.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Can anyone offer guidance for me please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show how do you use it in both cases?
What doesn't work and what can you see in VS output window?

Comment: In the WPF style I use 
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource HighlightColour}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundColour}"/>
    </Style>

Comment: I'm trying the use something like textbox.foreground = "{StaticResource DefaultColour}" so that I can change the colour programatically.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your ques.

Comment: @RichK if you want to change your Foreground dynamically - use binding to codebehind Property with INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.

But what is your question really? How to set foreground from resources, or how to set it dynamically?

Comment: @Shwed_Berlin I'm wanting to dynamically change the foreground colour when the text box gets and loses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comments

Use Style.Trigger for your Textbox:

```
<TextBox ...>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style  TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{...focusedcolor...}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{...unfocused...}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, that's what I needed.It's working just fine now.